# Vue DatePicker preserveState using inertiaJS

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, vuepic-vue-datepicker

Using `import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';`

combined with inertiaJS `useForm()`, but VueDatePicker `v-model` data value was not preserved.

I have this on my Vue page.

on my `<script setup>`

```
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const formData = useForm('Form1', {
    name: '',
    birthDate: ''
});

function submit() {
    formData.birthDate =  moment(formData.birthDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')

    formData.post(route('form.submit.path'), {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => {
            nextStep()
        }
    })
}
```

and on my `<template>`

```
<VueDatePicker v-model="formData.birthDate"
  class="datepicker" 
  calendar-class="datepicker_calendar"
  :enable-time-picker="false">
</VueDatePicker>
```

VueDatePicker value was not preserved even if I used inertiajs useForm() with [unique form key](https://inertiajs.com/remembering-state#:%7E:text=pass%20a%20unique%20form%20key)

How can I preserve `<VueDatePicker>` value when I browse to other pages using inertiajs-vue3?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you are overriding the `birthDate` variable value here:

```
formData.birthDate = moment(formData.birthDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Instead try to use `.transform()` method of the form object before calling the `.post()` method. See the documentation here: https://inertiajs.com/forms

With your example, it would look something like this:

```
function submit() {
    formData
      .transform((data) => ({
        ...data,
        birthDate: moment(data.birthDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
      }))
      .post(route('form.submit.path'), {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
        onSuccess: () => {
            nextStep()
        }
      })
}
```